# How to read the blockadblock script?

Tags: javascript, php, adblock

I'm wondering how to decode the script, I'm trying to customize the design but its so hard to read the code

there script is here:
https://blockadblock.com/blockadblock_basic_script.php

Comment: Look at GitHub, there is a repo BlockAdBlock and you can find a script which is not obfuscated.

Comment: @Galya Note that BlockAdBlock on GitHub is not the same as BlockAdblock on blockadblock.com.

Answer (score 2):

It's just encrypted inline with a function, no "obfuscation with a key"
Run the function without the initial "eval" here: http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html

and you'll get the code:

```js
Result = ;
var xcJQCflAmpis = '',
  KkUCuxqIgh = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) xcJQCflAmpis += KkUCuxqIgh.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * KkUCuxqIgh.length));
var VABjXzYzJp = 8,
  WSpSwDLzQd = 91,
  nsJjjBITZC = 178,
  neMuFFBFgq = 19,
  rMwHazIJjv = function(t) {
    var o = !1,
      i = function() {
        if (document.addEventListener) {
          document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e);
          window.removeEventListener('load', e)
        } else {
          document.detachEvent('onreadystatechange', e);
          window.detachEvent('onload', e)
        }
      },
      e = function() {
        if (!o && (document.addEventListener || event.type === 'load' || document.readyState === 'complete')) {
          o = !0;
          i();
          t()
        }
      };
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      t()
    } else if (document.addEventListener) {
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e);
      window.addEventListener('load', e)
    } else {
      document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', e);
      window.attachEvent('onload', e);
      var n = !1;
      try {
        n = window.frameElement == null && document.documentElement
      } catch (r) {};
      if (n && n.doScroll) {
        (function a() {
          if (o) return;
          try {
            n.doScroll('left')
          } catch (e) {
            return setTimeout(a, 50)
          };
          o = !0;
          i();
          t()
        })()
      }
    }
  };
window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''] = (function() {
      var t = {
        t$: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=',
        encode: function(e) {
          var d = '',
            l, r, i, s, c, a, n, o = 0;
          e = t.n$(e);
          while (o < e.length) {
            l = e.charCodeAt(o++);
            r = e.charCodeAt(o++);
            i = e.charCodeAt(o++);
            s = l >> 2;
            c = (l & 3) << 4 | r >> 4;
            a = (r & 15) << 2 | i >> 6;
            n = i & 63;
            if (isNaN(r)) {
              a = n = 64
            } else if (isNaN(i)) {
              n = 64
            };
            d = d + this.t$.charAt(s) + this.t$.charAt(c) + this.t$.charAt(a) + this.t$.charAt(n)
          };
          return d
        },
        decode: function(e) {
          var n = '',
            l, c, d, s, r, i, a, o = 0;
          e = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, '');
          while (o < e.length) {
            s = this.t$.indexOf(e.charAt(o++));
            r = this.t$.indexOf(e.charAt(o++));
            i = this.t$.indexOf(e.charAt(o++));
            a = this.t$.indexOf(e.charAt(o++));
            l = s << 2 | r >> 4;
            c = (r & 15) << 4 | i >> 2;
            d = (i & 3) << 6 | a;
            n = n + String.fromCharCode(l);
            if (i != 64) {
              n = n + String.fromCharCode(c)
            };
            if (a != 64) {
              n = n + String.fromCharCode(d)
            }
          };
          n = t.e$(n);
          return n
        },
        n$: function(t) {
          t = t.replace(/;/g, ';');
          var n = '';
          for (var o = 0; o < t.length; o++) {
            var e = t.charCodeAt(o);
            if (e < 128) {
              n += String.fromCharCode(e)
            } else if (e > 127 && e < 2048) {
              n += String.fromCharCode(e >> 6 | 192);
              n += String.fromCharCode(e & 63 | 128)
            } else {
              n += String.fromCharCode(e >> 12 | 224);
              n += String.fromCharCode(e >> 6 & 63 | 128);
              n += String.fromCharCode(e & 63 | 128)
            }
          };
          return n
        },
        e$: function(t) {
          var o = '',
            e = 0,
            n = c1 = c2 = 0;
          while (e < t.length) {
            n = t.charCodeAt(e);
            if (n < 128) {
              o += String.fromCharCode(n);
              e++
            } else if (n > 191 && n < 224) {
              c2 = t.charCodeAt(e + 1);
              o += String.fromCharCode((n & 31) << 6 | c2 & 63);
              e += 2
            } else {
              c2 = t.charCodeAt(e + 1);
              c3 = t.charCodeAt(e + 2);
              o += String.fromCharCode((n & 15) << 12 | (c2 & 63) << 6 | c3 & 63);
              e += 3
            }
          };
          return o
        }
      };
      var a = ['YWQtbGVmdA==', 'YWRCYW5uZXJXcmFw', 'YWQtZnJhbWU=', 'YWQtaGVhZGVy', 'YWQtaW1n', 'YWQtaW5uZXI=', 'YWQtbGFiZWw=', 'YWQtbGI=', 'YWQtZm9vdGVy', 'YWQtY29udGFpbmVy', 'YWQtY29udGFpbmVyLTE=', 'YWQtY29udGFpbmVyLTI=', 'QWQzMDB4MTQ1', 'QWQzMDB4MjUw', 'QWQ3Mjh4OTA=', 'QWRBcmVh', 'QWRGcmFtZTE=', 'QWRGcmFtZTI=', 'QWRGcmFtZTM=', 'QWRGcmFtZTQ=', 'QWRMYXllcjE=', 'QWRMYXllcjI=', 'QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMQ==', 'QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMg==', 'QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMw==', 'QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wNA==', 'RGl2QWQ=', 'RGl2QWQx', 'RGl2QWQy', 'RGl2QWQz', 'RGl2QWRB', 'RGl2QWRC', 'RGl2QWRD', 'QWRJbWFnZQ==', 'QWREaXY=', 'QWRCb3gxNjA=', 'QWRDb250YWluZXI=', 'Z2xpbmtzd3JhcHBlcg==', 'YWRUZWFzZXI=', 'YmFubmVyX2Fk', 'YWRCYW5uZXI=', 'YWRiYW5uZXI=', 'YWRBZA==', 'YmFubmVyYWQ=', 'IGFkX2JveA==', 'YWRfY2hhbm5lbA==', 'YWRzZXJ2ZXI=', 'YmFubmVyaWQ=', 'YWRzbG90', 'cG9wdXBhZA==', 'YWRzZW5zZQ==', 'Z29vZ2xlX2Fk', 'b3V0YnJhaW4tcGFpZA==', 'c3BvbnNvcmVkX2xpbms='],
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length),
        Y = t.decode(a[y]),
        b = Y,
        C = 1,
        f = '#EEEEEE',
        r = '#777777',
        g = '#adb8ff',
        w = '#FFFFFF',
        Q = '',
        W = 'Welcome!',
        v = 'It looks like you\'re using an ad blocker. That\'s okay.  Who doesn\'t?',
        p = 'But without advertising-income, we can\'t keep making this site awesome.',
        s = 'I understand, I have disabled my ad blocker.  Let me in!',
        o = 0,
        u = 0,
        n = 'moc.kcolbdakcolb',
        l = 0,
        M = e() + '.jpg';

      function h(t) {
        if (t) t = t.substr(t.length - 15);
        var n = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        for (var o = n.length; o--;) {
          var e = String(n[o].src);
          if (e) e = e.substr(e.length - 15);
          if (e === t) return !0
        };
        return !1
      };

      function m(t) {
        if (t) t = t.substr(t.length - 15);
        var e = document.styleSheets;
        x = 0;
        while (x < e.length) {
          thisurl = e[x].href;
          if (thisurl) thisurl = thisurl.substr(thisurl.length - 15);
          if (thisurl === t) return !0;
          x++
        };
        return !1
      };

      function e(t) {
        var o = '',
          e = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        t = t || 30;
        for (var n = 0; n < t; n++) o += e.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * e.length));
        return o
      };

      function i(o) {
        var i = ['YWRuLmViYXkuY29t', 'YWQubWFpbC5ydQ==', 'anVpY3lhZHMuY29t', 'YWQuZm94bmV0d29ya3MuY29t', 'cGFydG5lcmFkcy55c20ueWFob28uY29t', 'YS5saXZlc3BvcnRtZWRpYS5ldQ==', 'YWdvZGEubmV0L2Jhbm5lcnM=', 'YWR2ZXJ0aXNpbmcuYW9sLmNvbQ==', 'Y2FzLmNsaWNrYWJpbGl0eS5jb20=', 'cHJvbW90ZS5wYWlyLmNvbQ==', 'YWRzLnlhaG9vLmNvbQ==', 'YWRzLnp5bmdhLmNvbQ==', 'YWRzYXR0LmFiY25ld3Muc3RhcndhdmUuY29t', 'YWRzYXR0LmVzcG4uc3RhcndhdmUuY29t', 'YXMuaW5ib3guY29t', 'cGFydG5lcmFkcy55c20ueWFob28uY29t'],
          r = ['ZmF2aWNvbi5pY28=', 'YmFubmVyLmpwZw==', 'NDY4eDYwLmpwZw==', 'NzIweDkwLmpwZw==', 'c2t5c2NyYXBlci5qcGc=', 'MTM2N19hZC1jbGllbnRJRDI0NjQuanBn', 'YWRjbGllbnQtMDAyMTQ3LWhvc3QxLWJhbm5lci1hZC5qcGc=', 'Q0ROLTMzNC0xMDktMTM3eC1hZC1iYW5uZXI=', 'ZmF2aWNvbi5pY28=', 'YWQtbGFyZ2UucG5n', 'c3F1YXJlLWFkLnBuZw==', 'ZmF2aWNvbjEuaWNv', 'YmFubmVyX2FkLmdpZg==', 'bGFyZ2VfYmFubmVyLmdpZg==', 'd2lkZV9za3lzY3JhcGVyLmpwZw==', 'YWR2ZXJ0aXNlbWVudC0zNDMyMy5qcGc='];
        x = 0;
        spimg = [];
        while (x < o) {
          c = i[Math.floor(Math.random() * i.length)];
          d = r[Math.floor(Math.random() * r.length)];
          c = t.decode(c);
          d = t.decode(d);
          var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
          if (a == 1) {
            n = '//' + c + '/' + d
          } else {
            n = '//' + c + '/' + e(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 4) + '.jpg'
          };
          spimg[x] = new Image();
          spimg[x].onerror = function() {
            var t = 1;
            while (t < 7) {
              t++
            }
          };
          spimg[x].src = n;
          x++
        }
      };

      function A(t) {};
      return {
        ekgBSgaBPk: function(t, r) {
          if (typeof document.body == 'undefined') {
            return
          };
          var o = '0.1',
            r = b,
            e = document.createElement('DIV');
          e.id = r;
          e.style.position = 'absolute';
          e.style.left = '-5000px';
          e.style.top = '-5000px';
          e.style.height = '60px';
          e.style.width = '468px';
          var d = document.body.childNodes,
            a = Math.floor(d.length / 2);
          if (a > 15) {
            var n = document.createElement('div');
            n.style.position = 'absolute';
            n.style.height = '0px';
            n.style.width = '0px';
            n.style.top = '-5000px';
            n.style.left = '-5000px';
            document.body.insertBefore(n, document.body.childNodes[a]);
            n.appendChild(e);
            var i = document.createElement('DIV');
            i.id = 'banner_ad';
            i.style.position = 'absolute';
            i.style.left = '-5000px';
            i.style.top = '-5000px';
            document.body.appendChild(i)
          } else {
            e.id = 'banner_ad';
            document.body.appendChild(e)
          };
          l = setInterval(function() {
            if (e) {
              t((e.clientHeight == 0), o);
              t((e.clientWidth == 0), o);
              t((e.display == 'hidden'), o);
              t((e.visibility == 'none'), o);
              t((e.opacity == 0), o)
            } else {
              t(!0, o)
            }
          }, 1000)
        },
        bPqodbIKMt: function(e, m) {
          if ((e) && (o == 0)) {
            o = 1;
            window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].NhnwYPCjqO();
            window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].bPqodbIKMt = function() {
              return
            }
          } else {
            var p = t.decode('aW5zLmFkc2J5Z29vZ2xl'),
              c = document.querySelector(p);
            if ((c) && (o == 0)) {
              if ((WSpSwDLzQd % 3) == 0) {
                var d = 'Ly9wYWdlYWQyLmdvb2dsZXN5bmRpY2F0aW9uLmNvbS9wYWdlYWQvanMvYWRzYnlnb29nbGUuanM=';
                d = t.decode(d);
                if (h(d)) {
                  if (c.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0) {
                    o = 1;
                    window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].NhnwYPCjqO()
                  }
                }
              }
            };
            var f = !1;
            if (o == 0) {
              if ((nsJjjBITZC % 3) == 0) {
                if (!window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].ranAlready) {
                  var l = ['Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9hZHNlbnNlL3N0YXJ0L2ltYWdlcy9mYXZpY29uLmljbw==', 'Ly93d3cuZ3N0YXRpYy5jb20vYWR4L2RvdWJsZWNsaWNrLmljbw==', 'Ly9hZHZlcnRpc2luZy55YWhvby5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28=', 'Ly9hZHMudHdpdHRlci5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28=', 'Ly93d3cuZG91YmxlY2xpY2tieWdvb2dsZS5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28='],
                    s = l.length,
                    r = l[Math.floor(Math.random() * s)],
                    n = r;
                  while (r == n) {
                    n = l[Math.floor(Math.random() * s)]
                  };
                  r = t.decode(r);
                  n = t.decode(n);
                  i(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1);
                  var a = new Image(),
                    u = new Image();
                  a.onerror = function() {
                    i(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1);
                    u.src = n;
                    i(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1)
                  };
                  u.onerror = function() {
                    o = 1;
                    i(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1);
                    window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].NhnwYPCjqO()
                  };
                  a.src = r;
                  if ((neMuFFBFgq % 3) == 0) {
                    a.onload = function() {
                      if ((a.width < 8) && (a.width > 0)) {
                        window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].NhnwYPCjqO()
                      }
                    }
                  };
                  i(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1);
                  window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].ranAlready = !0
                };
                window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].bPqodbIKMt = function() {
                  return
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        NhnwYPCjqO: function() {
            if (u == 1) {
              var C = sessionStorage.getItem('babn');
              if (C > 0) {
                return !0
              } else {
                sessionStorage.setItem('babn', (Math.random() + 1) * 1000)
              }
            };
            var c = 'Ly95dWkueWFob29hcGlzLmNvbS8zLjE4LjEvYnVpbGQvY3NzcmVzZXQvY3NzcmVzZXQtbWluLmNzcw==';
            c = t.decode(c);
            if (!m(c)) {
              var h = document.createElement('link');
              h.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
              h.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
              h.setAttribute('href', c);
              document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(h)
            };
            clearInterval(l);
            document.body.innerHTML = '';
            document.body.style.cssText += 'margin:0px !important';
            document.body.style.cssText += 'padding:0px !important';
            var Q = document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth,
              y = window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight,
              a = document.createElement('DIV'),
              b = e();
            a.id = b;
            a.style.position = 'fixed';
            a.style.left = '0';
            a.style.top = '0';
            a.style.width = Q + 'px';
            a.style.height = y + 'px';
            a.style.backgroundColor = f;
            a.style.zIndex = '9999';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            var d = '<a href="http://blockadblock.com"><svg id="FILLVECTID1" width="160" height="40"><image id="FILLVECTID2" width="160" height="40" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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
```

Answer (score 0):

You can partially deobfuscate it simply by removing the `eval()` that the code is wrapped inside. The entirety of the code that's inside the `eval()` will return the stringified code so you just need to run it to get that string.

Sidenote: I usually use the [JsFormat](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat) plugin for Sublime Text for that. It evaluates the content of the `eval()` and also nicely formats the code afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full blockadblock standard script that you ask, just copy it and paste anywehere after open "body" and before closed "body" tag. Also you can change everything in this code, like: bgcolor, font, text, logo, button, delay time... everything.. in the end of the script. You'll see.

Your page code must be like this:

```
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Place this code snippet near the footer of your page before the close of the /body tag
// LEGAL NOTICE: The content of this website and all associated program code are protected under the Digital Millennium Copyright Act. Intentionally circumventing this code may constitute a violation of the DMCA.

eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){
e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){
while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}
return p});

var xcJQCflAmpis = '',
KkUCuxqIgh = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) xcJQCflAmpis += KkUCuxqIgh.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * KkUCuxqIgh.length));
var VABjXzYzJp = 8, //-- delay time in seconds
WSpSwDLzQd = 91,
nsJjjBITZC = 178,
neMuFFBFgq = 19,
rMwHazIJjv = function (t) {
    var o = !1,
        i = function () {
            if (document.addEventListener) {
                document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e);
                window.removeEventListener('load', e)
            } else {
                document.detachEvent('onreadystatechange', e);
                window.detachEvent('onload', e)
            }
        },
        e = function () {
            if (!o && (document.addEventListener || event.type === 'load' || document.readyState === 'complete')) {
                o = !0;
                i();
                t()
            }
        };
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        t()
    } else if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e);
        window.addEventListener('load', e)
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', e);
        window.attachEvent('onload', e);
        var n = !1;
        try {
            n = window.frameElement == null && document.documentElement
        } catch (r) {};
        if (n && n.doScroll) {
            (function a() {
                if (o) return;
                try {
                    n.doScroll('left')
                } catch (e) {
                    return setTimeout(a, 50)
                };
                o = !0;
                i();
                t()
            })()
        }
    }
};
window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''] = (function () {
var t = {
    t$: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=',
    encode: function (e) {
        var d = '',
            l, r, i, s, c, a, n, o = 0;
        e = t.n$(e);
        while (o < e.length) {
            l = e.charCodeAt(o++);
            r = e.charCodeAt(o++);
            i = e.charCodeAt(o++);
            s = l >> 2;
            c = (l & 3) << 4 | r >> 4;
            a = (r & 15) << 2 | i >> 6;
            n = i & 63;
            if (isNaN(r)) {
                a = n = 64
            } else if (isNaN(i)) {
                n = 64
            };
            d = d + this.t$.charAt(s) + this.t$.charAt(c) + this.t$.charAt(a) + this.t$.charAt(n)
        };
        return d
    },
    decode: function (e) {
        var n = '',
            l, c, d, s, r, i, a, o = 0;
        e = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, '');
        while (o < e.length) {
            s = this.t$.indexOf(e.charAt(o++));
            r = this.t$.indexOf(e.charAt(o++));
            i = this.t$.indexOf(e.charAt(o++));
            a = this.t$.indexOf(e.charAt(o++));
            l = s << 2 | r >> 4;
            c = (r & 15) << 4 | i >> 2;
            d = (i & 3) << 6 | a;
            n = n + String.fromCharCode(l);
            if (i != 64) {
                n = n + String.fromCharCode(c)
            };
            if (a != 64) {
                n = n + String.fromCharCode(d)
            }
        };
        n = t.e$(n);
        return n
    },
    n$: function (t) {
        t = t.replace(/;/g, ';');
        var n = '';
        for (var o = 0; o < t.length; o++) {
            var e = t.charCodeAt(o);
            if (e < 128) {
                n += String.fromCharCode(e)
            } else if (e > 127 && e < 2048) {
                n += String.fromCharCode(e >> 6 | 192);
                n += String.fromCharCode(e & 63 | 128)
            } else {
                n += String.fromCharCode(e >> 12 | 224);
                n += String.fromCharCode(e >> 6 & 63 | 128);
                n += String.fromCharCode(e & 63 | 128)
            }
        };
        return n
    },
    e$: function (t) {
        var o = '',
            e = 0,
            n = c1 = c2 = 0;
        while (e < t.length) {
            n = t.charCodeAt(e);
            if (n < 128) {
                o += String.fromCharCode(n);
                e++
            } else if (n > 191 && n < 224) {
                c2 = t.charCodeAt(e + 1);
                o += String.fromCharCode((n & 31) << 6 | c2 & 63);
                e += 2
            } else {
                c2 = t.charCodeAt(e + 1);
                c3 = t.charCodeAt(e + 2);
                o += String.fromCharCode((n & 15) << 12 | (c2 & 63) << 6 | c3 & 63);
                e += 3
            }
        };
        return o
    }
};
var a = ['YWQtbGVmdA==', 'YWRCYW5uZXJXcmFw', 'YWQtZnJhbWU=', 'YWQtaGVhZGVy', 'YWQtaW1n', 'YWQtaW5uZXI=', 'YWQtbGFiZWw=', 'YWQtbGI=', 'YWQtZm9vdGVy', 'YWQtY29udGFpbmVy', 'YWQtY29udGFpbmVyLTE=', 'YWQtY29udGFpbmVyLTI=', 'QWQzMDB4MTQ1', 'QWQzMDB4MjUw', 'QWQ3Mjh4OTA=', 'QWRBcmVh', 'QWRGcmFtZTE=', 'QWRGcmFtZTI=', 'QWRGcmFtZTM=', 'QWRGcmFtZTQ=', 'QWRMYXllcjE=', 'QWRMYXllcjI=', 'QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMQ==', 'QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMg==', 'QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wMw==', 'QWRzX2dvb2dsZV8wNA==', 'RGl2QWQ=', 'RGl2QWQx', 'RGl2QWQy', 'RGl2QWQz', 'RGl2QWRB', 'RGl2QWRC', 'RGl2QWRD', 'QWRJbWFnZQ==', 'QWREaXY=', 'QWRCb3gxNjA=', 'QWRDb250YWluZXI=', 'Z2xpbmtzd3JhcHBlcg==', 'YWRUZWFzZXI=', 'YmFubmVyX2Fk', 'YWRCYW5uZXI=', 'YWRiYW5uZXI=', 'YWRBZA==', 'YmFubmVyYWQ=', 'IGFkX2JveA==', 'YWRfY2hhbm5lbA==', 'YWRzZXJ2ZXI=', 'YmFubmVyaWQ=', 'YWRzbG90', 'cG9wdXBhZA==', 'YWRzZW5zZQ==', 'Z29vZ2xlX2Fk', 'b3V0YnJhaW4tcGFpZA==', 'c3BvbnNvcmVkX2xpbms='],
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length),
    Y = t.decode(a[y]),
    b = Y,
    C = 1,
    f = '#EEEEEE', //-- colors
    r = '#777777',
    g = '#adb8ff',
    w = '#FFFFFF',
    Q = '',
    W = 'Welcome!', //-- text
    v = 'It looks like you\'re using an ad blocker. That\'s okay.  Who doesn\'t?',
    p = 'But without advertising-income, we can\'t keep making this site awesome.',
    s = 'I understand, I have disabled my ad blocker.  Let me in!',
    o = 0,
    u = 0,
    n = 'moc.kcolbdakcolb', //-- blockaddblock.com link in left bottom
    l = 0,
    M = e() + '.jpg';

function h(t) {
    if (t) t = t.substr(t.length - 15);
    var n = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var o = n.length; o--;) {
        var e = String(n[o].src);
        if (e) e = e.substr(e.length - 15);
        if (e === t) return !0
    };
    return !1
};

function m(t) {
    if (t) t = t.substr(t.length - 15);
    var e = document.styleSheets;
    x = 0;
    while (x < e.length) {
        thisurl = e[x].href;
        if (thisurl) thisurl = thisurl.substr(thisurl.length - 15);
        if (thisurl === t) return !0;
        x++
    };
    return !1
};

function e(t) {
    var o = '',
        e = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    t = t || 30;
    for (var n = 0; n < t; n++) o += e.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * e.length));
    return o
};

function i(o) {
    var i = ['YWRuLmViYXkuY29t', 'YWQubWFpbC5ydQ==', 'anVpY3lhZHMuY29t', 'YWQuZm94bmV0d29ya3MuY29t', 'cGFydG5lcmFkcy55c20ueWFob28uY29t', 'YS5saXZlc3BvcnRtZWRpYS5ldQ==', 'YWdvZGEubmV0L2Jhbm5lcnM=', 'YWR2ZXJ0aXNpbmcuYW9sLmNvbQ==', 'Y2FzLmNsaWNrYWJpbGl0eS5jb20=', 'cHJvbW90ZS5wYWlyLmNvbQ==', 'YWRzLnlhaG9vLmNvbQ==', 'YWRzLnp5bmdhLmNvbQ==', 'YWRzYXR0LmFiY25ld3Muc3RhcndhdmUuY29t', 'YWRzYXR0LmVzcG4uc3RhcndhdmUuY29t', 'YXMuaW5ib3guY29t', 'cGFydG5lcmFkcy55c20ueWFob28uY29t'],
        r = ['ZmF2aWNvbi5pY28=', 'YmFubmVyLmpwZw==', 'NDY4eDYwLmpwZw==', 'NzIweDkwLmpwZw==', 'c2t5c2NyYXBlci5qcGc=', 'MTM2N19hZC1jbGllbnRJRDI0NjQuanBn', 'YWRjbGllbnQtMDAyMTQ3LWhvc3QxLWJhbm5lci1hZC5qcGc=', 'Q0ROLTMzNC0xMDktMTM3eC1hZC1iYW5uZXI=', 'ZmF2aWNvbi5pY28=', 'YWQtbGFyZ2UucG5n', 'c3F1YXJlLWFkLnBuZw==', 'ZmF2aWNvbjEuaWNv', 'YmFubmVyX2FkLmdpZg==', 'bGFyZ2VfYmFubmVyLmdpZg==', 'd2lkZV9za3lzY3JhcGVyLmpwZw==', 'YWR2ZXJ0aXNlbWVudC0zNDMyMy5qcGc='];
    x = 0;
    spimg = [];
    while (x < o) {
        c = i[Math.floor(Math.random() * i.length)];
        d = r[Math.floor(Math.random() * r.length)];
        c = t.decode(c);
        d = t.decode(d);
        var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
        if (a == 1) {
            n = '//' + c + '/' + d
        } else {
            n = '//' + c + '/' + e(Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 4) + '.jpg'
        };
        spimg[x] = new Image();
        spimg[x].onerror = function () {
            var t = 1;
            while (t < 7) {
                t++
            }
        };
        spimg[x].src = n;
        x++
    }
};

function A(t) {};
return {
    ekgBSgaBPk: function (t, r) {
        if (typeof document.body == 'undefined') {
            return
        };
        var o = '0.1',
            r = b,
            e = document.createElement('DIV');
        e.id = r;
        e.style.position = 'absolute';
        e.style.left = '-5000px';
        e.style.top = '-5000px';
        e.style.height = '60px';
        e.style.width = '468px';
        var d = document.body.childNodes,
            a = Math.floor(d.length / 2);
        if (a > 15) {
            var n = document.createElement('div');
            n.style.position = 'absolute';
            n.style.height = '0px';
            n.style.width = '0px';
            n.style.top = '-5000px';
            n.style.left = '-5000px';
            document.body.insertBefore(n, document.body.childNodes[a]);
            n.appendChild(e);
            var i = document.createElement('DIV');
            i.id = 'banner_ad';
            i.style.position = 'absolute';
            i.style.left = '-5000px';
            i.style.top = '-5000px';
            document.body.appendChild(i)
        } else {
            e.id = 'banner_ad';
            document.body.appendChild(e)
        };
        l = setInterval(function () {
            if (e) {
                t((e.clientHeight == 0), o);
                t((e.clientWidth == 0), o);
                t((e.display == 'hidden'), o);
                t((e.visibility == 'none'), o);
                t((e.opacity == 0), o)
            } else {
                t(!0, o)
            }
        }, 1000)
    },
    bPqodbIKMt: function (e, m) {
        if ((e) && (o == 0)) {
            o = 1;
            window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].NhnwYPCjqO();
            window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].bPqodbIKMt = function () {
                return
            }
        } else {
            var p = t.decode('aW5zLmFkc2J5Z29vZ2xl'),
                c = document.querySelector(p);
            if ((c) && (o == 0)) {
                if ((WSpSwDLzQd % 3) == 0) {
                    var d = 'Ly9wYWdlYWQyLmdvb2dsZXN5bmRpY2F0aW9uLmNvbS9wYWdlYWQvanMvYWRzYnlnb29nbGUuanM=';
                    d = t.decode(d);
                    if (h(d)) {
                        if (c.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0) {
                            o = 1;
                            window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].NhnwYPCjqO()
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            var f = !1;
            if (o == 0) {
                if ((nsJjjBITZC % 3) == 0) {
                    if (!window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].ranAlready) {
                        var l = ['Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9hZHNlbnNlL3N0YXJ0L2ltYWdlcy9mYXZpY29uLmljbw==', 'Ly93d3cuZ3N0YXRpYy5jb20vYWR4L2RvdWJsZWNsaWNrLmljbw==', 'Ly9hZHZlcnRpc2luZy55YWhvby5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28=', 'Ly9hZHMudHdpdHRlci5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28=', 'Ly93d3cuZG91YmxlY2xpY2tieWdvb2dsZS5jb20vZmF2aWNvbi5pY28='],
                            s = l.length,
                            r = l[Math.floor(Math.random() * s)],
                            n = r;
                        while (r == n) {
                            n = l[Math.floor(Math.random() * s)]
                        };
                        r = t.decode(r);
                        n = t.decode(n);
                        i(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1);
                        var a = new Image(),
                            u = new Image();
                        a.onerror = function () {
                            i(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1);
                            u.src = n;
                            i(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1)
                        };
                        u.onerror = function () {
                            o = 1;
                            i(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1);
                            window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].NhnwYPCjqO()
                        };
                        a.src = r;
                        if ((neMuFFBFgq % 3) == 0) {
                            a.onload = function () {
                                if ((a.width < 8) && (a.width > 0)) {
                                    window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].NhnwYPCjqO()
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        i(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1);
                        window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].ranAlready = !0
                    };
                    window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].bPqodbIKMt = function () {
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    NhnwYPCjqO: function () {
        if (u == 1) {
            var C = sessionStorage.getItem('babn');
            if (C > 0) {
                return !0
            } else {
                sessionStorage.setItem('babn', (Math.random() + 1) * 1000)
            }
        };
        var c = 'Ly95dWkueWFob29hcGlzLmNvbS8zLjE4LjEvYnVpbGQvY3NzcmVzZXQvY3NzcmVzZXQtbWluLmNzcw==';
        c = t.decode(c);
        if (!m(c)) {
            var h = document.createElement('link');
            h.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
            h.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
            h.setAttribute('href', c);
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(h)
        };
        clearInterval(l);
        document.body.innerHTML = '';
        document.body.style.cssText += 'margin:0px !important';
        document.body.style.cssText += 'padding:0px !important';
        var Q = document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth,
            y = window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight,
            a = document.createElement('DIV'),
            b = e();
        a.id = b;
        a.style.position = 'fixed';
        a.style.left = '0';
        a.style.top = '0';
        a.style.width = Q + 'px';
        a.style.height = y + 'px';
        a.style.backgroundColor = f;
        a.style.zIndex = '9999';
        document.body.appendChild(a); //-- original link, you can delete or change
        var d = '<a href="http://blockadblock.com"><svg id="FILLVECTID1" width="160" height="40"><image id="FILLVECTID2" width="160" height="40" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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">;</svg></a>';
        d = d.replace('FILLVECTID1', e());
        d = d.replace('FILLVECTID2', e());
        var i = document.createElement('DIV');
        i.innerHTML = d;
        i.style.position = 'absolute';
        i.style.bottom = '30px';
        i.style.left = '30px';
        i.style.width = '160px';
        i.style.height = '40px';
        i.style.zIndex = '10000';
        i.style.opacity = '.6';
        i.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        i.addEventListener('click', function () {
            n = n.split('').reverse().join('');
            window.location.href = '//' + n
        });
        document.getElementById(b).appendChild(i);
        var o = document.createElement('DIV'),
            Z = e();
        o.id = Z;
        o.style.position = 'fixed';
        o.style.top = y / 7 + 'px';
        o.style.minWidth = Q - 120 + 'px';
        o.style.minHeight = y / 3.5 + 'px';
        o.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        o.style.zIndex = '10000';
        o.style.cssText += 'font-family: "Arial Black", Helvetica, geneva, sans-serif !important';
        o.style.cssText += 'line-height: normal !important';
        o.style.cssText += 'font-size: 16pt !important';
        o.style.cssText += 'text-align: center !important';
        o.style.cssText += 'padding: 12px !important';
        o.style.display += 'block';
        o.style.marginLeft = '30px';
        o.style.marginRight = '30px';
        o.style.borderRadius = '15px';
        document.body.appendChild(o);
        o.style.boxShadow = '0px 14px 24px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
        o.style.visibility = 'visible';
        var Y = 30,
            A = 22,
            x = 18,
            M = 18;
        if ((window.innerWidth < 640) || (screen.width < 640)) {
            o.style.zoom = '50%';
            o.style.cssText += 'font-size: 18pt !important';
            o.style.marginLeft = '45px;';
            i.style.zoom = '65%';
            var Y = 22,
                A = 18,
                x = 12,
                M = 12
        };  //-- here is your adblock warning page
        o.innerHTML = '<h3 style="color:#999;font-size:' + Y + 'pt;color:' + r + ';font-family:Helvetica, geneva, sans-serif;font-weight:200;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;text-align:center;">' + W + '</h3><h1 style="font-size:' + A + 'pt;font-weight:500;font-family:Helvetica, geneva, sans-serif;color:' + r + ';margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;text-align:center;">' + v + '</h1><hr style=" display: block;margin-top: 0.5em;margin-bottom: 0.5em;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; border:1px solid #CCC; width: 25%;text-align:center;"><p style="font-family:Helvetica, geneva, sans-serif;font-weight:300;font-size:' + x + 'pt;color:' + r + ';text-align:center;">' + p + '</p><p style="margin-top:35px;"><div onmouseover="this.style.opacity=.9;" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;"  id="' + e() + '" style="cursor:pointer;font-size:' + M + 'pt;font-family:Helvetica, geneva, sans-serif; font-weight:300;border-radius:15px;padding:10px;background-color:' + g + ';color:' + w + ';padding-left:60px;padding-right:60px;width:60%;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" onclick="window.location.reload();">' + s + '</div></p>'
    }
}
})();
 window.cfVDoTdmsN = function (t, e) {
var r = Date.now,
    i = window.requestAnimationFrame,
    a = r(),
    n, o = function () {
        r() - a < e ? n || i(o) : t()
    };
i(o);
return {
    clear: function () {
        n = 1
    }
}
};
var BGWRSzJxTu;
if (document.body) {
document.body.style.visibility = 'visible'
};
rMwHazIJjv(function () {
if (document.getElementById('babasbmsgx')) {
    document.getElementById('babasbmsgx').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('babasbmsgx').style.display = 'none'
};
BGWRSzJxTu = window.cfVDoTdmsN(function () {
    window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].ekgBSgaBPk(window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].bPqodbIKMt, window['' + xcJQCflAmpis + ''].nipmDSFuLH)
}, VABjXzYzJp * 1000)
});
</script>

</body>
```

Example (switch addblock on): http://besedka.ho.ua/adblock.html

Have fun ;)

Answer (score -1):

My guess is script is Obfuscate using some tool.

> Javascript Obfuscator converts the JavaScript source code into obfuscated and completely unreadable form, preventing it from analysing and theft. It's a 100% safe JavaScript minifier and the best JavaScript compressor

so to deobfuscate script you need secret key, which was used to Obfuscate.

Comment: so its impossible for me to convert it.

Comment: sadly yes! it's impossible to convert without having secret key.