# JS: Useless loop on Image onerror -- what for?

Tags: javascript, image, onerror

I am tinkering around with some third party code and this caught my attention:

```
spimg[x] = new Image();
spimg[x].onerror = function () {
    var t = 1;
    while (t < 7) { t++ }
};
spimg[x].src = imageSrc;
```

After trying to load an image, if an error ocurrs, it just sets up an empty loop that finishes quite quickly.

What could be the use of such an error function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop

Comment: it looks like it is from here, maybe: [How to read the blockadblock script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38067889)

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik You'd need to count to a whole lot more than 7 to add a delay.

Comment: leftover/unfinished code for an attempt to retry

Comment: @NinaScholz That's exactly where it's from! (I didn't take it from the post, rather, I unobfuscated it myself.)